# Cómo puedo hacer funcionar mi proyecto web con Netbeans + Tomcat en Linux?

Tags: java, netbeans, tomcat

Les traigo el siguiente problema.
Tengo un computador con un sistema operativo `Linux/KDE-neon` con `Netbeans` 8.1 y 
`Apache Tomcat/8.5.31`. Tomcat anda bien por si solo pero cuando lo ejecuto en netbeans me salta error.

He tratado de buscar en Google alguna solución, pero la mayoría esta orientada a Windows. Espero poder hallar una salida aqui.

```
### Main:

Waiting for Tomcat...
Starting of Tomcat failed.
/home/sebastian/NetBeansProjects/TallerPrograAvanzada/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1045: Deployment error: Starting of Tomcat failed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 minutes 1 second)
```

#### Apache:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/sebastian/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/sebastian/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/sebastian/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/sebastian/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/sebastian/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
15-May-2018 22:04:49.214 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
15-May-2018 22:04:49.218 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Apr 27 2018 20:24:25 UTC
15-May-2018 22:04:49.218 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.31.0
15-May-2018 22:04:49.218 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
15-May-2018 22:04:49.218 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.13.0-41-generic
15-May-2018 22:04:49.218 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
15-May-2018 22:04:49.219 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
15-May-2018 22:04:49.219 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_171-b11
15-May-2018 22:04:49.219 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
15-May-2018 22:04:49.219 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /home/sebastian/tomcat
15-May-2018 22:04:49.220 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /home/sebastian/tomcat
15-May-2018 22:04:49.220 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/sebastian/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
15-May-2018 22:04:49.220 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
15-May-2018 22:04:49.220 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
15-May-2018 22:04:49.221 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
15-May-2018 22:04:49.221 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
15-May-2018 22:04:49.221 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
15-May-2018 22:04:49.221 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/sebastian/tomcat
15-May-2018 22:04:49.222 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/sebastian/tomcat
15-May-2018 22:04:49.223 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/sebastian/tomcat/temp
15-May-2018 22:04:49.223 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent La biblioteca nativa de Apache Tomcat basada en ARP que permite un rendimiento óptimo en entornos de desarrollo no ha sido hallada en java.library.path: [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/../jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/../jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
15-May-2018 22:04:49.422 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
15-May-2018 22:04:49.442 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
15-May-2018 22:04:49.457 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
15-May-2018 22:04:49.460 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
15-May-2018 22:04:49.461 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 816 ms
15-May-2018 22:04:49.509 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Arrancando servicio [Catalina]
15-May-2018 22:04:49.509 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
15-May-2018 22:04:49.522 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Despliegue del directorio [/home/sebastian/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] de la aplicación web
15-May-2018 22:04:49.986 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/home/sebastian/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [463] ms
15-May-2018 22:04:49.986 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Despliegue del directorio [/home/sebastian/tomcat/webapps/examples] de la aplicación web
15-May-2018 22:04:50.375 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/home/sebastian/tomcat/webapps/examples] has finished in [389] ms
15-May-2018 22:04:50.375 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Despliegue del directorio [/home/sebastian/tomcat/webapps/manager] de la aplicación web
15-May-2018 22:04:50.407 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/home/sebastian/tomcat/webapps/manager] has finished in [31] ms
15-May-2018 22:04:50.407 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Despliegue del directorio [/home/sebastian/tomcat/webapps/docs] de la aplicación web
15-May-2018 22:04:50.428 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/home/sebastian/tomcat/webapps/docs] has finished in [21] ms
15-May-2018 22:04:50.429 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Despliegue del directorio [/home/sebastian/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] de la aplicación web
15-May-2018 22:04:50.470 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/home/sebastian/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [40] ms
15-May-2018 22:04:50.474 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
15-May-2018 22:04:50.498 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
15-May-2018 22:04:50.508 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 1046 ms
```

### Log de apache:

```
15-May-2018 15:19:32.137 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
15-May-2018 15:19:32.138 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
15-May-2018 15:19:32.139 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@581d9e55')
15-May-2018 15:26:10.564 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
15-May-2018 15:26:10.564 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
15-May-2018 15:26:16.436 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
15-May-2018 15:26:16.436 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
15-May-2018 15:26:16.438 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@452a0d99')
15-May-2018 15:34:15.330 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
15-May-2018 15:34:15.330 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
15-May-2018 21:04:31.324 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
15-May-2018 21:04:31.324 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
15-May-2018 21:04:31.326 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@3ed9603a')
15-May-2018 21:07:22.378 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
15-May-2018 21:07:22.378 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
15-May-2018 21:08:23.754 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
15-May-2018 21:08:23.754 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
15-May-2018 21:08:23.756 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@205a2656')
15-May-2018 21:32:16.341 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
15-May-2018 21:32:16.341 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
15-May-2018 21:34:23.137 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
15-May-2018 21:34:23.137 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
15-May-2018 21:34:23.139 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@8a9c5ea')
15-May-2018 21:49:23.645 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
15-May-2018 21:49:23.645 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
15-May-2018 21:49:32.539 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
15-May-2018 21:49:32.539 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
15-May-2018 21:49:32.541 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@581d9e55')
15-May-2018 21:50:05.343 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
15-May-2018 21:50:05.343 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
15-May-2018 21:50:12.116 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
15-May-2018 21:50:12.116 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
15-May-2018 21:50:12.118 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@8a9c5ea')
15-May-2018 21:52:17.530 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
15-May-2018 21:52:17.533 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
15-May-2018 21:52:39.200 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
15-May-2018 21:52:39.200 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
15-May-2018 21:52:39.202 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@581d9e55')
15-May-2018 22:04:39.591 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
15-May-2018 22:04:39.591 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
15-May-2018 22:04:50.367 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
15-May-2018 22:04:50.367 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
15-May-2018 22:04:50.369 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@452a0d99')
```

Comment: No aparece nada relevante en el log expuesto. Estas seguro que no hay mas?

Comment: No sé cómo lo hace Netbeans, pero Eclipse tiene su propia carpeta de configuración para Tomcat... con lo que tanto los WAR como los ficheros con los logs no están donde esperarías. Comprueba la configuración de Netbeans

Comment: Logre cumplir con mi objetivo, pero con un servidor glassFish. 4.1.1. Adjuntare un link de GlassFish 4.1.1 http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/4.1.1/release/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Logre montar el programa web, en vez de ocupar tomcat  Tomcat/8.5.31. Cambie a GlassFish 4.1.1 y no tuve problemas. 
adjunto el link de GlassFish [aquí](http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/4.1.1/release/index.html)